# AIR Native Extension - missing "library.swf"

Tags: ios-simulator, air-native-extension

I'm trying to package an AIR 3.3 Native Extension for the iOS-Simulator with the following command:

> adt -package -target ane MyANE.ane extension.xml -swc MySWC.swc
>   -platform iPhone-x86 library.swf MyLib.a

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Missing 'library.swf' for platform: iPhone-x86
```

I am creating the swc with the Flex 4.6 SDK overlayed with AIR 3.3. I'm using -swf-verion 14 and the 3.1 Namespace. I'm extracting the library.swf file from the same swc.

It seems like I'm doing everything by the books so I have no idea why it won't package.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution is to run the command from the same path/level as the MySWC.swc file. I was using

```
-platform iPhone-x86 /Users/Me/library.swf
```

this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios-simulator.html